# How do I use a custom renamer with FernFlower?

Tags: java, decompiling

I currently have a working setup of FernFlower, which is like this;

I have the `fernflower.jar` and a `fern.bat` file which contents are:

```
title FernFlower
java -jar fernflower.jar -dgs=1 -ren=1 C:\Users\bernhardkiv\Desktop\test\test-obf.jar C:\Users\bernhardkiv\Desktop\test\src
```

And the argument `-ren 1` makes it so any methods and fields that have names lower than 3 characters (or something like that) get renamed to `func_blah` or `field_blah` (respectivally, methods get the `func_` name and fields get the `field_` name.

In the readme of fernflower there is this section:

```
 5. Renaming identifiers

Some obfuscators give classes and their member elements short, meaningless and above all 
ambiguous names. Recompiling of such code leads to a great number of conflicts. Therefore it is
advisable to let the decompiler rename elements in its turn, ensuring uniqueness of each identifier.

Option 'ren' (i.e. -ren=1) activates renaming functionality. Default renaming strategy goes as follows:
 - rename an element if its name is a reserved word or is shorter than 3 characters
 - new names are built according to a simple pattern: (class|method|field)_<consecutive unique number>  
 You can overwrite this rules by providing your own implementation of the 4 key methods invoked by the decompiler while renaming. Simply pass a class that implements de.fernflower.main.extern.IIdentifierRenamer in the option 'urc' (e.g. -urc=com.mypackage.MyRenamer) to Fernflower.
 The class must be available on the application classpath.
```

Through which, I have read through and understand how it works, but I am having trouble with adding my own implementation of the renaming function.

I have created a class, which implements IIdentifierRenamer, which contents are as follows;

```
public class MyRenamer implements IIdentifierRenamer {

@Override
public String getNextClassname(String arg0, String arg1) {
    return "_" + arg0 + "_" + arg1;
}

@Override
public String getNextFieldname(String arg0, String arg1, String arg2) {
    return "_" + arg0 + "_" + arg1 + "_" + arg2;
}

@Override
public String getNextMethodname(String arg0, String arg1, String arg2) {
    return "_" + arg0 + "_" + arg1 + "_" + arg2;
}

@Override
public boolean toBeRenamed(int arg0, String arg1, String arg2, String arg3) {

    System.out.println(arg0 + ", " + arg1 + ", " + arg2 + ", arg3");
    return true;
}

}
```

First things first, before you question why I return all of the arguments for the nextMethod/Class/Field methods, it is so that I could explore and see what those arguements actually are, because there is absolutely no documentation AFAIK.

I compiled this class into a jar, named `custre.jar`, and put it in the same folder as my `fern.bat`.

I am now unsure of what to do to continue, please reply if you know anything about FernFlower, and if you can help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to add your custre.jar into the classpath. Then you need to specify the custom renamer class to FernFlower:

```
java -cp /path/to/custre.jar -jar fernflower.jar -dgs=1 -ren=1 -urc=MyRenamer C:\Users\bernhardkiv\Desktop\test\test-obf.jar C:\Users\bernhardkiv\Desktop\test\src
```

(Replace the `/path/to/custre.jar` with the actual path on your system),

Comment: Hi, I just tried that, but I get this output: `INFO: User supplied renamer class MyRenamer found. Loading...` and then I get `WARNING: Class MyRenamer couldn't be loaded.`

Comment: I'll need more information to answer this one. What java/javac version are you using, any security profiles etc. Sorry I don't have time to debug it ATM.

Comment: how much information do you need exactly? can you tell me what exactly you need to know? And what are security profiles?

Comment: Even though you did not help me, I'm still giving you the reputation so that it doesn't go to waste.

Answer (score 5):

Okay, it took some time to figure this out. First, notice that there is a class in fernflower source that implements default renaming:

```
src/org/jetbrains/java/decompiler/modules/renamer/ConverterHelper.java
```

Copy this file as a template to your own location, adjust to suit your needs. I changed package to:

```
package jimm3rs.renamer;
```

And added debug message output to the `toBeRenamed` method:

```
System.out.println("Custom Renamer: processing [" + classname + "]");
```

Then compiled:

```
javac -cp ~/fernflower/trunk/fernflower.jar ConverterHelper.java
```

Next thing is to instruct fernflower to use this custom renamer:

```
java -classpath fernflower.jar:/home/martin/mycode/ org.jetbrains.java.decompiler.main.decompiler.ConsoleDecompiler -dgs=1 -ren=1 -urc=jimm3rs.renamer.ConverterHelper /home/martin/Downloads/idea-IC-141.1532.4/lib/boot.jar .
```

Note that in the above code directory `/home/martin/mycode/` contains a subdirectory named `jimm3rs` which in turn contains directory named `renamer` which stores our custom renamer class. This could be changed to use a jar if you wish with an extra step.

One useful tip when debugging class loading is to specify `-Dsun.misc.URLClassPath.debug=true` option to java.

Finally I'd like to say that using -jar syntax to run fernflower.jar didn't do
the trick: custom class specified via `-classpath` is not visible to fernflower.

Comment: I think you've got a `:` in your classpath when it should be a `;`. With the semi-colon, this technique works for me. I can't make an edit of less than six characters, which seems bizarre on a programming website.

Comment: Just learned that it's `:` on unix. The separator being platform-dependent also seems bizarre.